# Requiring a module in webpack.config.js not working

Tags: javascript, webpack

The following require works in webpack.config.js:

```
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require("monaco-editor-webpack-plugin");
```

This one doesn't:

```
const monacoEditor = require("monaco-editor");
```

Even though both of these are in the dependencies section of package.json, and both have folders in node_modules for this package (and when I delete node_modules and reinstall the folders come back).  There must be something else preventing it from picking up the package.  Is there anything special about webpack.config.js with respect to what it can resolve?

Answer (score 0):

The first option is actually well documented in their tutorial; **[Option 1: Using the Monaco Editor WebPack Plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/HEAD/docs/integrate-esm.md#option-1-using-the-monaco-editor-webpack-plugin)**. In their own words: *This is the easiest method, and it allows for options to be passed into the plugin in order to select only a subset of editor features or editor languages.*
Although what was used was [ES6 import syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

```js
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';
```

There is no proper documentation for [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules-commonjs-modules).

Comment: Are you using this on a NodeJS application? I think this should be typically used [on the browser though.](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/843ff9b9d704de0960e145108c22be73f5d77c4e/samples/browser-esm-webpack/dist/index.html)

Comment: import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

That syntax doesn't work in webpack.config.js, it seems to be only for the js/ts files be compiled